# Datastax 4 installation on original RaspberryPi

Tags: raspberry-pi, cassandra-2.0, datastax

I've just begun working with Datastax/Cassandra.

I've set up my home PC quite easily.

I've also got an original RaspberryPi I'd like to use to set up a small cluster (I may add more Pi's later).

My question is: will Datastax 4 run on an original RaspberryPi?

I'm not looking for rocket ship speeds, just want to ensure I can get the cluster up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can.  It would not be capable of handling very much load at all, but has been used purely for demo purposes.  DataStax even has a RaspPi cluster built out as a demo in their HQ lobby- [DataStax Dev blog example](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/32-node-raspberry-pi-cassandra-cluster).

Generally speaking you'll get better performance using the second gen Raspberry Pi because of the hardware/processing upgrades, but it is possible with gen 1 - just make sure your expectations are equivalent to the low level hardware on those Raspberry Pi's!

Comment: Thanks Phil. This pi is a loaner. If I add more they'll be pi2s

Comment: Thanks again Phil, I was able to get things running on my original Pi.